# Combine separate Day, Month, Year to Datetime

Tags: c#, .net-core

How would I be able to combine 3 separate datetime fields pointing to the same property. Date, Month and Year. While debugging, it shows that the value is  -e.g. - "01,1,2018". I believe the comma's are the problem for the datetime format. I tried doing a replace but don't think I am doing it correctly. Had to convert to string then convert back to a datetime. Any suggestions? Please look at my scenario below:

```
<label asp-for="Startdate">Employee Start Date</label>
<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="select">
        <select asp-for="Startdate" class="month">
            <option>Month...</option>
            <option value="01">January</option>
            <option value="02">February</option>
            <option 
        </select>
        <img src="~/images/icons/triangle.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="select">
        <select asp-for="Startdate" class="day">
            <option>Day...</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option 
        </select>
        <img src="~/images/icons/triangle.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="select">
        <select asp-for="Startdate" class="year" id="start-year">
            <option disabled selected>Year...</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
            <option 
        </select>
```

C#:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = ("0:dd/MM/yyyy"))]
public DateTime? Startdate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why not use a Date picker?

Comment: Custom implementation is done in the front end to separate day, month and year so unfortunately it's not an option

Comment: how are you sending the value to server? is it ajax? or form data? anyways why not create a new Date(year,month,day) from your controls and pass that value?

Comment: var date = new DateTime(year, month, day);

Comment: The commas are because you have three inputs with the same name (the asp-for attribute controls the name of the generated input field).  When you have multiple form elements with the same name, browsers will post the value to the server as comma separated values.  One possible, albeit "dirty" solution would be to change the StartDate property to be a string, and then simply create a new DateTIme property whose getters/setters read and parse the value from the string property (i.e replace commas to dots/slashes etc.

Comment: @HaukurHaf how could I implement that in a property?                              public DateTime? Startdate { get { return Convert.ToDateTime(Date); } set { Startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(Date.Replace(',', '-')); } }

Comment: @KarthikGanesan it is sent via form data

Comment: @kevinchirayath Yes, something like that.   

You probably also have to replace the commas to a dash in the getter.

Comment: awesome, thanks guys

Comment: @HaukurHaf can you tell me what im doing incorrectly please?  [NotMapped]
        public DateTime? Date { get { return Startdate; } set { var date = Date.ToString().Replace(',', '-'); value = Convert.ToDateTime(date); } }
public DateTime? Startdate { get; set; }

Comment: `public String Startdate { get; set; } // <--- This property should get mapped from the request and contain the date in the format day,month,year - needs to be a string

    [NotMapped]
    public DateTime? Date { // <--- You can use this property to access the date, it will replace the the commas in Startdate with dashes and parse the resulting string as a DateTime object
        get { return DateTime.Parse(Startdate.Replace(",", "-")); }
    }`

Comment: Great, thanks a lot

Comment: how about this, looks a little better too right? public DateTime? Startdate { get { return Convert.ToDateTime(Day + '-' + Month + '-' + Year); } set { Startdate = value; } }  [NotMapped]
        public string Day { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string Month { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string Year { get; set; }